# Not able to uninstall Managed Package because of community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, managed-package, chargent

I have a managed package (Chargent Anywhere) which consist a lightning component named "Chargent_Payment_Central".

I have a community in my org and that community is not using "Chargent_Payment_Central" component in any page but yes it is being shown on the custom component list.

So while I am trying to uninstall "Chargent Anywhere" it gives any error because of community.
I am not able to figure out how to uninstall the package. (Tried to uninstall after deactivating the community but that didn't work and I can not delete the community).

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to publish the community? There is two layers for community, published and draft - you might removed the component from the draft version, after publishing the community it should have been removed from the published version. Note that sometime even this solution won’t work and due to something that looks like a bug in communities metadata you might need to open a support case to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in my previous project, so I removed the reference `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes` from my component.  After that, it will not show on the custom lightning component. Finally, you can uninstall your package.

Comment: Hey
The lightning component is from a managed package and I can not update it,

Comment: for a managed package, you can't edit the lightning component. For your issue, I also need to check.

Comment: https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-delete-components-from-a-managed-released-package/  -  check this one may be it will help you.

Comment: Indeed as other said this solution is not relevant for a managed package.